# How to Group By on multiple column in a pig script

Tags: apache-pig

What should be pig equivalent script of the below SQL query:

```
SELECT fld1, fld2, fld3, SUM(fld4)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY fld1, fld2, fld3;
```

**For Table1:**

```
A    B   C  2    X   Y   Z
A    B   C  3    X   Y   Z
A    B   D  2    X   Y   Z
A    C   D  2    X   Y   Z
A    C   D  2    X   Y   Z
A    C   D  2    X   Y   Z
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
A    B   C  5           
A    B   D  2           
A    C   D  6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Ref** : https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/basic.html#GROUP, you can
>   find a multi-group example

For your usecase below code should be suffice

```
A = load 'input.csv' using PigStorage(',')  AS (fld1:chararray,fld2:chararray,fld3:chararray,fld4:long,fld5:chararray,fld6:chararray,fld7:chararray);
B = FOREACH(GROUP A BY (fld1,fld2,fld3)) GENERATE FLATTEN(group) AS (fld1,fld2,fld3), SUM(A.fld4) AS fld4_aggr;
DUMP B;
```

Comment: Thanks it worked... :)

What I eventually came up with was:


A = load 'input.csv' using PigStorage(',')  AS (fld1:chararray,fld2:chararray,fld3:chararray,fld4:long,fld5:chararray,fld6:chararray,fld7:chararray);


group_A = Group A by (fld1, fld2, fld3);


B = foreach group_A generate group.fld1, group.fld2, group.fld3, sum(A.fld4) as sum_fld4;


DUMP B;